# "/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:540:in `materialize': Could not find" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

hi this is my 1st time making a docker image. after making an docker image of ruby on rails application and when running the image i am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:540:in `materialize': Could not find mysql2-0.5.6, rails-6.1.7.7, sqlite3-1.7.2, puma-5.6.8, sass-rails-6.0.0, webpacker-5.4.4, turbolinks-5.2.1, activesupport-6.1.7.7, jquery-rails-4.6.0, jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0, jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1, nokogiri-1.15.5-x86_64-linux, jbuilder-2.11.5, bootsnap-1.18.3, bootstrap-5.2.3, image_processing-1.12.2, byebug-11.1.3, activemodel-6.1.7.7, web-console-4.2.1, rack-mini-profiler-2.3.4, listen-3.9.0, spring-4.1.3, capybara-3.39.2, selenium-webdriver-4.9.0, webdrivers-5.3.1, actioncable-6.1.7.7, actionmailbox-6.1.7.7, actionmailer-6.1.7.7, actionpack-6.1.7.7, actiontext-6.1.7.7, actionview-6.1.7.7, activejob-6.1.7.7, activerecord-6.1.7.7, activestorage-6.1.7.7, railties-6.1.7.7, sprockets-rails-3.4.2, mini_portile2-2.8.5, nio4r-2.7.0, sassc-rails-2.1.2, rack-proxy-0.7.7, semantic_range-3.0.0, turbolinks-source-5.2.0, concurrent-ruby-1.2.3, i18n-1.14.4, minitest-5.22.2, tzinfo-2.0.6, zeitwerk-2.6.13, rails-dom-testing-2.2.0, thor-1.3.1, racc-1.7.3, msgpack-1.7.2, autoprefixer-rails-10.4.16.0, popper_js-2.11.8, mini_magick-4.12.0, ruby-vips-2.2.1, bindex-0.8.1, rack-2.2.8.1, rb-fsevent-0.11.2, rb-inotify-0.10.1, addressable-2.8.6, matrix-0.4.2, mini_mime-1.1.5, rack-test-2.1.0, regexp_parser-2.9.0, xpath-3.2.0, rexml-3.2.6, rubyzip-2.3.2, websocket-1.2.10, websocket-driver-0.7.6, mail-2.8.1, rails-html-sanitizer-1.6.0, builder-3.2.4, erubi-1.12.0, globalid-1.2.1, marcel-1.0.4, method_source-1.0.0, rake-13.1.0, sprockets-4.2.1, sassc-2.4.0, tilt-2.3.0, execjs-2.9.1, ffi-1.16.3, public_suffix-5.0.4, websocket-extensions-0.1.5, net-imap-0.3.7, net-pop-0.1.2, net-smtp-0.4.0.1, loofah-2.22.0, date-3.3.4, net-protocol-0.2.2, crass-1.0.6, timeout-0.4.1 in locally installed gems (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:266:in `specs_for'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/setup.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/setup.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
        from /app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
```

This is my `Dockerfile` code for reference:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/

COPY Gemfile ./
RUN gem update --system 3.2.3
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.4.22
RUN bundle install
RUN bundle update



ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems


ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/rails" ]

CMD [ "s" , "-b" , "0.0.0.0" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'
gem 'mysql2'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.7', '>= 6.1.7.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.7'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.15', '>= 1.15.4'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '~>5.2.0'
gem "image_processing", ">= 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
gem 'activemodel', '~> 6.0'
group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

i even tried deleting gemlock.file as i thought there might be an mismatch in the dependencies but after running RUN install bundle it didnt generate a new gemlock.file.

can anyone please let me know where i am going wrong.